# 2 columns responsive independent layout 1 overflow

Tags: html, css, angularjs, responsive-design, angular-material

Using Angular material you can crate in easy way a responsive layout. Right now I'm using 2 columns but they should are independent with 2 overflow like in this example i made: http://jsfiddle.net/2f6qscrp/227/
The problem is the responsive; The columns goes below on mobile, and to the right/left on larger devices correctly but they still maintain the 2 overflow per column instead create one main overflow that encloses both columns. Is there any way to fix it?

```
<div ng-app="home" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="scroll">
  <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" class="scroll">
    <div flex class="blue">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In hendrerit venenatis neque ut lacinia. Sed quis tortor vitae massa ornare aliquam. Cras vel aliquam tellus. Maecenas eleifend arcu eros, a cursus dui tempor sed. Aenean dignissim consectetur turpis ut scelerisque. Nullam ullamcorper ut sapien at convallis. Maecenas justo enim, lobortis ac leo at, venenatis dapibus sapien. Maecenas elementum urna a est eleifend mollis. Mauris vel ex blandit, aliquam urna eu, eleifend libero. Vestibulum commodo porta auctor. Fusce quis vulputate metus. Vestibulum commodo rutrum orci at efficitur. Sed luctus elit ut viverra porttitor. Donec cursus luctus purus ac vehicula. Cras ac ornare nibh, eget tempor nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Ut bibendum, nibh at ultrices convallis, eros nisl congue lacus, at sodales mauris nunc in velit. Vivamus molestie magna aliquet, varius velit in, posuere nunc. Sed a feugiat odio. Duis eu nisl quis diam aliquam interdum at quis turpis. In mollis lobortis erat in congue. Nulla et scelerisque ipsum. Phasellus imperdiet eu lacus eu lacinia. Cras vitae tempor magna.

Aenean venenatis mauris nibh, sit amet varius diam condimentum eu. Curabitur efficitur massa magna. Duis pretium sem ac consequat egestas. Proin lobortis mauris vitae urna pulvinar, a tincidunt orci facilisis. In porta eleifend fermentum. Vestibulum accumsan, metus a condimentum tristique, augue nisl placerat eros, id posuere nunc orci vel metus. Integer at massa efficitur, auctor neque nec, placerat nisl. Cras fringilla, nisi ut accumsan facilisis, dolor enim placerat elit, non venenatis turpis dui in tellus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus sollicitudin odio ac nisi fermentum dapibus. Cras euismod tortor quis consequat porta. Suspendisse semper vehicula ultricies. Quisque maximus sollicitudin justo at rhoncus. Donec eu vestibulum mauris, at consequat tortor.

Fusce sollicitudin a justo vitae convallis. Pellentesque interdum, purus at mollis molestie, metus tortor sagittis eros, vitae mattis lorem leo in sapien. Vivamus porttitor diam eu quam lacinia, vel commodo dolor venenatis. Mauris magna est, ele
    </div>
    <div flex class="red">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In hendrerit venenatis neque ut lacinia. Sed quis tortor vitae massa ornare aliquam. Cras vel aliquam tellus. Maecenas eleifend arcu eros, a cursus dui tempor sed. Aenean dignissim consectetur turpis ut scelerisque. Nullam ullamcorper ut sapien at convallis. Maecenas justo enim, lobortis ac leo at, venenatis dapibus sapien. Maecenas elementum urna a est eleifend mollis. Mauris vel ex blandit, aliquam urna eu, eleifend libero. Vestibulum commodo porta auctor. Fusce quis vulputate metus. Vestibulum commodo rutrum orci at efficitur. Sed luctus elit ut viverra porttitor. Donec cursus luctus purus ac vehicula. Cras ac ornare nibh, eget tempor nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Ut bibendum, nibh at ultrices convallis, eros nisl congue lacus, at sodales mauris nunc in velit. Vivamus molestie magna aliquet, varius velit in, posuere nunc. Sed a feugiat odio. Duis eu nisl quis diam aliquam interdum at quis turpis. In mollis lobortis erat in congue. Nulla et scelerisque ipsum. Phasellus imperdiet eu lacus eu lacinia. Cras vitae tempor magna.

Aenean venenatis mauris nibh, sit amet varius diam condimentum eu. Curabitur efficitur massa magna. Duis pretium sem ac consequat egestas. Proin lobortis mauris vitae urna pulvinar, a tincidunt orci facilisis. In porta eleifend fermentum. Vestibulum accumsan, metus a condimentum tristique, augue nisl placerat eros, id posuere nunc orci vel metus. Integer at massa efficitur, auctor neque nec, placerat nisl. Cras fringilla, nisi ut accumsan facilisis, dolor enim placerat elit, non venenatis turpis dui in tellus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus sollicitudin odio ac nisi fermentum dapibus. Cras euismod tortor quis consequat porta. Suspendisse semper vehicula ultricies. Quisque maximus sollicitudin justo at rhoncus. Donec eu vestibulum mauris, at consequat tortor.

Fusce sollicitudin a justo vitae convallis. Pellentesque interdum, purus at mollis molestie, metus tortor sagittis eros, vitae mattis lorem leo in sapien. Vivamus porttitor diam eu quam lacinia, vel commodo dolor venenatis. Mauris magna est, elementum nec erat id, tristique lacinia tellus. Integer varius id nisl vitae aliquam. Nullam commodo neque et sapien laoreet gravida. Morbi finibus dapibus ipsum, ac maximus lacus condimentum ut.

Mauris accumsan, felis ac vestibulum faucibus, ligula tellus pretium leo, quis feugiat ligula turpis a velit. In sit amet velit dui. Nunc ultricies sem gravida erat posuere, tempus molestie orci tempor. Sed maximus bibendum laoreet. Vestibulum ac placerat felis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus euismod eget leo a imperdiet. Maecenas eu pretium purus, ut volutpat eros.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.scroll {
   min-height: 100%;
   height:100%;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #0D47A1;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height:100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: #B71C1C;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height:100%;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.scroll {
   min-height: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #0D47A1;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height:100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: #B71C1C;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height:100%;
}

@media (max-width:1600px) {
  .blue, .red, .scroll {
    height: auto;
    min-height: auto;
  }
}
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/2f6qscrp/228/

Comment: In this way the 2 columns in large devices aren't independent. It's still 1 overflow

Comment: @End.Game Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

- You would like larger screens to show two columns (red and blue in
  your mockups), each of which can scroll vertically independently as
  long as the content is long enough to overflow.
- On smaller screens (mobile) you would like the two columns to become one long scrollable column.

You can use media queries to achieve this. For example:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
   .red,
   .blue { width: 100%; }
}
```

Adding that to your JSFilddle's CSS will create the effect I think you are after. You can widen and narrow your browser window to see the impact it has.

*(Quick update: I've chosen the max-width of 600px as an arbitrary mobile-like measure. You can update this as needed, ideally based on the way the content and layout works in situ)*